# My usb HSM came initialized and now I do not know how to use it

Tags: pkcs#11, hsm

I am new to HSM and seems like working with pkcs11 is the most popular approach. 
I plugged in a USB HSM and when I listed it, it shows it was already initialized. How can I log into it without knowing the user and SO pins ?

Slot 18446744073709551610

```
Slot info:
    Description:      Virtual hotplug slot                                            
    Manufacturer ID:  OpenSC (www.opensc-project.org) 
    Hardware version: 0.0
    Firmware version: 0.0
    Token present:    no
```

Slot 1

```
Slot info:
    Description:      Identiv uTrust 3512 SAM slot Token [CCID Interface] (55511725602

    Manufacturer ID:  OpenSC (www.opensc-project.org) 
    Hardware version: 0.0
    Firmware version: 0.0
    Token present:    yes
Token info:
    Manufacturer ID:  www.CardContact.de              
    Model:            PKCS#15 emulated
    Hardware version: 24.13
    Firmware version: 2.5
    Serial number:    DECC0300697     
    Initialized:      yes
    User PIN init.:   yes
    Label:            SmartCard-HSM (UserPIN)
```

Can I get help for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to contact your HSM supplier and ask him to provide you PIN values.

Comment: Hello jariq. Thank you. Is this how they normally work ? I would have thought that they would be uninitialized and I would use my pins to initialize the HSM. Is this your experience as well ?

Comment: @ejohnson if you ordered new unit then it definitely has to be in uninitialized and untampered state otherwise you cannot trust it is secure.